# In Cocos2d , How to move background sprite image?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2

I am working on car game,i want to move background image in portrait mode (size of image is 320 × 1024),for this i don't want to use CCParallaxNode to move the background image and not even a TiledMap.Is there any other way to move background in portrait mode.

After 2 min i want to increase the speed of background sprite, can any one help me how to do this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean that, you want to scroll your backGround down wards.. ?
Like infinite scrolling back ground..?

Comment: change the sprite's position property every update? Use CCMoveTo action?

Answer (score 1):

Just set the position for the background sprite on the scheduled update method.

```
-(void) anUpdate:(ccTime)dt {

    bgSprite.position = ccp(<new x coordinate>, <new y coordinate>);
```

Answer (score 1):

in update method position your bgImage:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)dt{
    total_time_ += dt;
    if(total_time_> 2*60)
      speed_ *=2;
    bgSprite.position = ccp(bgSprite.position.x, bgSprite.position.y+speed_*dt);
}
```